# Not Updating the OpportunityAmount field according to business logic

Tags: apex

We have `Opportunityproduct` object. `Opportunity.Amount` will roll up all `TotalPrice` values from child `OpportunityProduct` records, I want to  change the logic so that `TotalPrice` field is populated with the same value as in `Print SKU Total Price`. `Opportunity.PrintAmount` will remain unchanged
The now visible `Opportunity.DigitalAmount` should be `(Opportunity.Amount - Opportunity.PrintAmount)`. Anyone can provide me sample code for this?

Comment: If you're using the standard `Opportunity` and `OpportunityLineItem` objects (which it sounds like you are doing), why not use a rollup summary field? What have you tried so far (this sounds like a "do it for me" request, which don't do very well on this site)?

Comment: Also, you seem to be hopping between different field names without explanation. Where did `Opportunity.PrintAmount` come from? You don't mention this field at all before saying that it "will remain unchanged". At any rate, I think you can accomplish this with rollups, formula fields, and workflow rules + field updates.